# Password Validation Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, validation

very new to javascript/jquery.  I'm trying to display an error message if the user enters less than the desired number of characters and tries to move their mouse button out of the text box.  I am unable to get the code to work.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body id="bg">
        <div class="main">
        <form id="fillout">
            <legend id="lgnd">
                Login Credentials
            </legend>
            <label id="usrname">
                Username:
                <input type="text" name="user" maxlength="15">
            </label>
            <br/>
            <label id="pwd">
                Password:
                <input id="entered" type="text" name="pass" maxlength="20">
            </label>
            <p id="feedback"></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var $feedback = $('li#feedback');
            var $username = $('label#usrname');
            var $entered = $('#entered');
            var minpass = 8;
            $username.on('mouseout', function(){
                if ($entered.length < minpass)
                    $feedback.text("Password must be six characters")
            })

        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

two small changes should get you what you need.

```
 //get the selected or entered value first

 var _val = $entered.val()

//now check the length of it

 _val.length < minpass
```

Comment: I made the changes and it's still not working as desired.  Not sure how to proceed

Comment: Check your console. Are you getting any JS errors? Also, share the updated code. I would like to see how you structured those revisions.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wqvup700/

Error on line 40 reading, "Uncaught TypeError: $feedback.text is not a function
    at HTMLLabelElement.<anonymous> (index.html:40)
    at HTMLLabelElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.js:5206)
    at HTMLLabelElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.2.1.js:5014)"

Comment: li#feedback does not exist. li#feedback should be just #feedback or p#feedback (you dont have it as a list item, you have it as a "p" id.

Comment: Currently in class.  I will try to fix my code afterwards and write back.  Thank you very much for the continued help

Comment: I attempted to change to a submit button serving the same purpose but am still stuck.  Mind taking a look?
https://jsfiddle.net/htwfqeo0/

Comment: I made a couple corrections for you. This seems to work. You were missing a parenthesis on your conditional and the new var you added should be placed inside the click handler block so that it grabs the value on click, not on load.  Note - you are going to want to prevent default on that form submission if your values dont validate. Right now, it validates, but sends the submission anyways.

http://jsfiddle.net/htwfqeo0/5/

Answer (score 1):

- 1) Don’t forget the semicolons and the brackets, very important
- 2) The length you want is for the value in the element and not the element itself

  > ($entered.val()).length; 
  >   and not 
  >   $entered.length;
- 3) include an else to make the message go away or replace the message with another if the condition is fulfilled.
- 4) If the label has an id using the id alone will perform the same purpose you want you don’t have to include the element tag.

This will do what you wanted

```js
        $(function(){
            var $feedback = $('#feedback');
            var $username = $('#usrname');
            var $entered = $('#entered');
            var minpass = 8;
            $username.on('mouseout', function(){
                if (($entered.val()).length < minpass){
                    $feedback.text("Password must be six characters");
                }else{ $feedback.text("proceed message"); }
            });
        });
```

however

it may not be a good idea to count the characters entered on mouseout as you are planning since one may never hover over eventhandler or even select the textbox using a keyboard or touchscreen hence defeating the whole purpose of the count. You would rather validate on submission of the form or even just when the focus is shifted from the textbox. Plus why put the event handler on the username when testing the password? I hope this helps though…

Comment: Currently in class.  I will try and fix my code and write back in a bit.  Thank you for your help

Comment: I attempted to change to a submit button serving the same purpose but am still stuck.  Mind taking a look?
https://jsfiddle.net/htwfqeo0/